# Did the Wu-Tang Clan ever appear in the comics that they referenced?

Tags: marvel, comics

The Wu-Tang Clan is one of the most prolific rap groups of all time. Their lyrics take inspiration from various sources, from martial arts films to comic books. Characters from Spider-Man to Doctor Doom are referenced in their songs. The members Method Man and Ghostface Killah also have nicknames deriving from Marvel Comics, calling themselves Johnny Blaze (Ghost Rider) and Tony Starks (Iron Man) respectively.

Have Method Man, Ghostface Killah, or the rest of the Wu-Tang Clan been referenced/"appeared" in the source material that they have referenced in their songs? I know that Meth appeared in the Luke Cage series and Ghost appeared in a deleted scene in *Iron Man*, but what about the comics? Has Johnny Blaze ever met Johnny Blaze?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell they have never appeared in any Marvel comics. That said they have been referenced several times, for example, [*Secret Empire Vol. 1* Issue 3](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Secret_Empire_Vol_1_3), [*Falcon Vol. 2* Issue 2](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Falcon_Vol_2_2) and [*Deadpool: Assassin Vol. 1* Issue 1](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Deadpool:_Assassin_Vol_1_1):

[image: Deadpool mentions the Wu-Tang Clan]